# systemd: controlling timing of execution in *.service file

Tags: scripting, systemd

I've managed to get my script to run on shutdown or restart, however, I get an error, which is I think is caused by the script being run too late. The *.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=My special shutdown script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/home/PL/bin/umountb2.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would guess that the answer is the `before=` or `wants=` field.

The reason I say there is a problem is that umountb2.sh does 2 basic things: it unmounts a file system (which succeeds) then it calls `cryptsetup luksClose`. The last call returns an error. Even though I'm capturing its output and redirecting it to /dev/kmsg, I don't see any messages, just the ones the `echo` commands make. This is why I believe it is being called at the wrong time.

Here's a sample of the script I'm running where the problem happens.

```
cryptsetup luksClose b258
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "you gotta problem pal!"
```

See, `cryptsetup` doesn't output anything that I can see (am I looking in the wrong place?) so the only output I get is what I make myself.

Edit: actually, I just did a test, and the `umount` in my script failed this time. But I think it's down to the same problem: timing.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: "_The last call returns an error._" How do you know? [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the diagnostic output.

Comment: @J_H The message is "you gotta problem pal". I updated the post to include a cope snippet which explains why the feedback I'm getting is so impoverished.

Comment: cryptsetup has return codes: 1 wrong parameters, 2 no permission (bad
       passphrase), 3 out of memory, 4 wrong device specified, 5 device
       already exists or device is busy. Also accepts `--debug` and `--verbose`

Comment: Systemd unmounts everything before poweroff. You're probably in a race with `umount.target`, dependency of `systemd-poweroff.service`. See `systemd‐poweroff.service(8)`.

Comment: @Opux: As you said on the other site, you think you need this to unmount an encrypted file... Do you know for sure that this is necessary though? Such tracking of implicit mount dependencies is already part of systemd – not just for nested mounts, but generally for loop mounts as well. If your script runs "too late" (i.e. when the encrypted filesystem has already been unmounted), doesn't that by itself already show that you don't need to unmount it manually?

Comment: @u1686_grawity are you sure that's how it works though? Because it would have to first unmount the encrypted file system, then close the luks device, and only after doing that would it be safe to unmount /home. Can you be sure it would interlace the mounts with a call to `cryptsetup luksClose`?

Comment: It's a dependency-based init system (that's kind of the whole _thing_ about systemd) – if you configure mounts in /etc/fstab and devices in /etc/crypttab, then by design it knows that /home/opux/encrypted depends on /dev/mapper/b258 (or more precisely, that home-opux-encrypted.mount depends on dev-mapper-b258.device, which depends on systemd-cryptsetup@b258.service, which depends on home.mount), so in turn it knows that they need to be torn down in reverse order, i.e. if A depends on B, then stop(B) always waits for stop(A) to finish.

Comment: @jrpear I tried a bunch of tests and I didn't get any errors this time. Then I ran a more real test, where I was logged in and using the mount. When I tried to restart I got the error "/home/b2: target is busy". Now the workaround is obvious: just logout then restart, but this just goes to show that I don't know what I'm doing and I need to understand the timing of all this better.

Comment: [2/2] For everything else (i.e. stray mounts or mapper devices that weren't systemd-managed), the final shutdown phase will go into a loop of unmount-detach-unmount-detach (though IIRC this phase became smarter at some point). If you have a manual /dev/mapper/encrypted that wasn't stopped because it had no corresponding .service, the worst thing that would happen is that the regular attempt to unmount /home will get EBUSY and it'll be taken care of in the final stage. (Or similarly, attempts to disassemble a device will get EBUSY if it's mounted, but that'll be unmounted next.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Ah, well that's the thing, I haven't done anything in /etc/fstab and /etc/crypttab. Should I? I see you're fairly confident that the process is backstopped anyway, but should I also be placing entries in those files too?